# Xamarin Android Hamburger menu doesn't do anything (OnOptionsItemSelected doesn't run)

Tags: android, xamarin.android

So, to start off, I have been following a tutorial on getting the navigation drawer working. When I get to the part where he tests he is able to tap on the hamburger to open up the sidebar, mine doesn't. I can swipe to open it up, however, tapping the button doesn't do anything. It seems like no one else has this problem

Main Activity XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
  app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
  app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
  android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Dumby"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
  android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
  android:layout_width="240dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="start"
  android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
  android:divider="#818181"
  android:dividerHeight="1dp"
  android:background="#E3F2FD" />
```

Main Activity CS file

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    private SupportToolbar mToolbar;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mLeftDrawer;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);


        mToolbar = FindViewById<SupportToolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        mDrawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
        mLeftDrawer = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.left_drawer);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            mDrawerLayout,
            Resource.String.openDrawer,
            Resource.String.closeDrawer);
        SetSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout.AddDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.SyncState();
    }
    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        mDrawerToggle.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        //Toast.MakeText(this, "EEEE", ToastLength.Long);

        return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Here is the Action Bar Drawer Toggle Class just in case

```
 using SupportActionBarDrawerToggle = Android.Support.V7.App.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
 namespace Android_App_V2
 {
   class ActionBarDrawerToggle: SupportActionBarDrawerToggle
   {
    private AppCompatActivity mHostActivity;
    private int mClosedResource;
    private int mOpenResource;
    public ActionBarDrawerToggle(AppCompatActivity host, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, int openedResource,
      int closedResource) : base(host, drawerLayout, openedResource, closedResource)
    {
        mHostActivity = host;
        mOpenResource = openedResource;
        mClosedResource = closedResource;
    }

    public override void OnDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
    {
        base.OnDrawerOpened(drawerView);
    }

    public override void OnDrawerClosed(View drawerView)
    {
        base.OnDrawerClosed(drawerView);
    }

    public override void OnDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)
    {
        base.OnDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
    }

    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}}
```

Comment: The `DrawerLayout` is covering the `Toolbar` and intercepting touch events. If you mean for the drawer to open below the `Toolbar` vertically, then just add `android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"` to the opening `<DrawerLayout>` tag. If, instead, you want the drawer to open over the `Toolbar` as well, then move the `<Toolbar>` to inside the innermost `<RelativeLayout>`. You won't need the outer `<RelativeLayout>`, then, if nothing else other than the `<DrawerLayout>` is going inside it.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks, that seemed to have fixed it